# Which tense to choose

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect

There are a couple of  sentences:

> The water froze and caused the pipe to burst.

If it is a succession of past events it should be Past Simple.
But if the first part happened earlier, it should be :
The water had frozen and caused the pipe to burst.So, can it be Past Perfect, or this sentence must be written in Past Simple?

> Year by year the population of the West increased.

Should it be increased (Past Simple) or was  increasing(Past Continuous) ? Because, I guess, Past Simple does not belong here .

I don't know which tense to choose. There is no extra context, just sentences on their own.

Comment: Both of these are ungrammatical: "The water had frozen and caused the pipe to burst." — "Year by year the population of the West increasing." (Note: you *might* be able to get away with the first one, but only by assuming you really mean "and *had* caused the pile to burst." Best to keep them both in the same tense.)

Comment: There are 2 separate questions here. The second (increased/increasing) is unrelated to the first (about succession of two actions).

Comment: Thank you, if the sentence starts with " year by year!" , it is the indication of Present Continuous, isnt it? So, we can't say " Year by year the population of the West increased" .We must say "Year by year the population of the West was increasing". Am I right?